# Should I follow One Test Class per Class Pattern Or usecase Pattern to write test cases

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am learner in writing Junit Test Cases. I have seen writing Junit cases Pattern that We usually make test class for each class indivisually by their name and write test cases for each method of that class in its respective class so that maximum code coverage can occur.

What I was thinking If I make test cases for my feature that would be better choice because In future any number of methods Signature changes I don't have to change or create again unnecessary test cases for those modified methods or newly created. Because that moment I would have certain test cases for my developed feature. So my test cases are running fine for particular feature then I can be sure in minimum number of test cases code that everything is fine.

By keeping this I don't have to write test cases for each and every methods of each class. Is it a good way?

Comment: Not sure that Mockito tag makes sense here...

Answer (score 1):

Well, test cases are written for a reason. Each and every methods have to be working properly as expected. If you only do test cases for the feature level, how do you find exactly where the error occurred and how confidently you can ship your code to next level?
The better approach will be to do unit test cases for each class and do an integration test to make sure everything works good.

Answer (score 1):

> by keeping this I don't have to write test cases for each and every
>   methods of each class. Is it a good way?

In this case you write only integration tests and no unit tests.

Writing tests for use cases is really nice but it is not enough because it is hard to cover all cases of all methods invoked in an integration test because there may have a very important number of branches while it is much easier in an unit test.
Besides, a use case test may be successful for bad reasons : thanks to side effects between multiple methods invoked.
By writing an unit test you protect yourself against this kind of issue.

Definitively, unit and integration tests are are not opposed but complementary.  So you have to write both to get a robust application.

Answer (score 1):

We found success in utilizing both.  By default we use one per class.  But when particular use-cases come up, e.g. use-cases that involve multiple classes or use cases where the existing boiler plate testing code prevents the use case from being properly tested, then we would create a test class for that scenario.